# Half-hidden numeric labels of ticks in JSlider - Netbeans GUI

Tags: java

I was using Netbeans GUI to create a JSlider. Then I added the ticks and max and min values as follows:

```
    slider.setMinorTickSpacing(10);
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
    slider.setPaintTicks(true);Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labels =
            new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    labels.put(0, new JLabel("0"));
    labels.put(20, new JLabel("20"));
    labels.put(40, new JLabel("40"));
    labels.put(60, new JLabel("60"));
    labels.put(80, new JLabel("80"));
    labels.put(100, new JLabel("100"));
    slider.setLabelTable(labels);      
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
```

It was working fine until during one of the runs, half the numbers were hidden, as in 20, 40.. its not visible. But it is there. Here:

[image]

How do I correct this? This: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html tells nothing.

Comment: Can you adjust the preferred (min/max) size of the slider?

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the problem. The code you posted doesn't show the context of how the slider is used. It may be a layout manager problem.

Comment: This is the code where I use JSlider, No real use otherwise in the rest of the program. This problem occurred when I tried adding a JLabel over the rest of the contents to form a background for the panel.

Comment: @StefanFreitag: setting preferred dimension doesn't help.

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835430/how-to-set-size-of-a-jslider

Comment: I used a panel inside the panel and that helps. Seems like this is solved.